# Can "kaz-yos/eval-in-repl" use the prexisting "inf-ruby" console started by robe mode

Tags: org-babel, repl, ruby

I've been using org babel to execute ruby code,
works well but

- wrapping blocks with begin_src/end_src is cumbersome
- no live output - i have to wait till the whole process finishes to see output

Suppose I have this bit of text in a fundamental buffer

```
puts `pwd`
puts RUBY_VERSION
```

When I press `C-c a` I want this executed using ruby interpreter.
I started writing a defun for it like this:

```
(defun my-execute-region-with-ruby()
   (interactive))
```

I've found a package/function that does it (https://github.com/kaz-yos/eval-in-repl/blob/master/eval-in-repl-ruby.el)

but looking for a different solution or to amend the solution in that package.
My issues:

1) When the ruby code block is executed, the "system ruby binary" is used, which is 99% of the time not the binary used by for example the rails project I'm working on
   2) there should be a way to indicate the "cd working directory" when executing the ruby code block.

I've noticed "github.com/kaz-yos/eval-in-repl" uses a live inf-ruby buffer
for the execution. I already (always) have an inf-ruby consiole
running because I use "github.com/dgutov/robe", so was wondering how
I can tell "eval-in-repl-ruby.el" to re-use the preexisting "inf-ruby"
repl, because the robe repl already has it's `cd` set correctly,
and as a result the ruby version is correct too because
'RBENV' detects the appropriate ruby version
to use by reading the "project/.ruby-version" file.

Comment: Please pose only one question per question, rather than a list of *"My issues"*.

Answer (score -1):

I think I figured out a solution.

https://github.com/nonsequitur/inf-ruby/issues/126